# Go lang slice columns from 2d array?

Tags: go, multidimensional-array, slice

I'm curious, how do you create a column slice from a 2d Array?

I have an array for a game board for Tic-Tac-Toe, and I'm trying to create a column slice, but my slices are coming out identical.

```
/* Just trying to get rows and columns working first */

func() isWin() bool {
  win := make([]char, SIZE*2)
  for i:= range BOARD {
    fmt.Println("Row")
    win[i] = check(BOARD[i][0:SIZE])
    fmt.Println("Column")
    win[i+SIZE] = check(BOARD[0:SIZE][i])
  }
return false
}

func() check(slice []char) (char) {
  fmt.Println(slice)
  return "-"
}
```

I give it the following input:

```
[E E E E]
[E E E E]
[X O E E]
[X O E E]
```

And I get a return of

```
Row
[X O E E]
Column
[X O E E]
```

But I want a return of

```
Row
[X O E E]
Column
[E E X X]
```

How do I make this slice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible with the slice syntax. You think that `x[i][0:n]` will get you all the columns of row `i`. What it actually does is returning the columns `0` to `n` from row `i`.

You have to use a loop to get a column:

```
func boardColumn(board [][]char, columnIndex int) (column []char) {
    column = make([]char, 0)
    for _, row := range board {
        column = append(column, row[columnIndex])
    }
    return
}
```

The code you label with 'Row' is actually the code I would have expected to deliver the columns:

```
win[i] = check(BOARD[0:SIZE][i])
```

Semantically the slice indices say: take the `i`th element of all elements from zero to SIZE.
But, as already mentioned, Go slices work differently. [Try for yourself](http://play.golang.org/p/OqNalVfjlq):

```
x := [][]int{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
fmt.Println(x[0:2]) // [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
fmt.Println(x[0:2][0]) // [1,2,3]
```

As you can see in line two of the example above, `x[0:2]` returns the full 2d slice. Consequently
taking the first element returns the first row of that 2d slice.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps. I edited my code because I mixed up "rows" and "columns".

Comment: What is `SIZE`? Do you have to call `len() - 1` there?